# Doctrine/DBAL lastInsertId() returns 0

Tags: php, silex

I am using Doctrine/DBAL quite long time, but I have a little problem using executeUpdate and getting the last insert Id.
It always returns 0 , but the DB Entry is set. the coloumn id is set and it is AutoIncrement and PRIMARY in my DB.

Here is the function which copies my entry to another table.

```
$copy = $app['db']->executeUpdate('INSERT INTO `pd_user_model` (
                `campaign_id`,
                ...
                `created`)  
            SELECT `campaign_id`,
                ...                 
                NOW() 
            FROM `pd_pass_model` WHERE `campaign_id` = ?', array($campaignID));

echo "INSERT<br>";
echo "LAST INSERT:" .  $app['db']->lastInsertId(); 


//RETURN VALUE 
INSERT
LAST INSERT:0
```

Anybody any hints for me.
Thanks so far!

Comment: It is because you are doing a SELECT after the INSERT statement.
Try just the insert query then check the value of lastInsertId()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lastInsertId returns the last **generated** id. In your use case, you are not generating an id. You are already providing an id to your query therefore, the lastInsertId function will return 0 because it did not generate an ID.

From the [MYSQL doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

> LAST_INSERT_ID() (with no argument) returns a BIGINT (64-bit) value
>   representing the first automatically generated value that was set for
>   an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the most recently executed INSERT
>   statement to affect such a column.